# creating daemon processing from server socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I have one socket, which act as server while executed and response some results.
First I compile it: `g++ -o a daemon.cpp dictionary.cpp -lpthread c++11`
then execute : `./a`

Now it will listen for the request on some port.

I want that one I create the object file `a`, it should not manually executed. Rather work as daemon file, which continously listen for the request.

I saw using `fork()` id something can be done. But I could not correct place in my below code:

variable declation I have removed:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
void *SocketHandler(void *);

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    pthread_t thread_id = 0;


    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (hsock == -1) 
    {
        printf("Error initializing socket %dn", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

    p_int = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if ((setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1) 
        || (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *) p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)) 
    {
        printf("Error setting options %dn", errno);
        free(p_int);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    free(p_int);

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(hsock, (sockaddr *) & my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %dn", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

    if (listen(hsock, 10) == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    //Now lets do the server stuff

    addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

    int pid;
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid<0)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
    else if(pid>0){
    //this is parent process, exit now
         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // again no goto
   }
   else{
        //this is child or daemon
       unmask();
   pid_t childid = setsid();

    while (true) 
    {
        printf("waiting for a connectionn\n");
        csock = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        if ((*csock = accept(hsock, (sockaddr *) & sadr, &addr_size)) != -1) 
        {
            printf("---------------------nReceived connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &SocketHandler, (void *) csock);
            pthread_detach(thread_id);
        } 
        else 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno);
        }
    sleep(60);
    }

FINISH:
    ;
}

void *SocketHandler(void *lp)
{   
    char *ch;/* stores references to 50 words. */
    char *ch2[50] = { 0 };  
    char *excluded_string;
    char *word;

    if ((bytecount = recv(*csock, (char*) rcv.c_str(), rcv.length(), 0)) == -1) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d \n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }    

    do 
    {
        bytesReceived = recv(*csock, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);
        // append string from buffer.

        if ( bytesReceived == -1 ) 
        { 
            fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d \n", errno);
            goto FINISH;
        } 
        else 
            rcv.append( buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend() );

    } while ( bytesReceived == MAX_BUF_LENGTH );

    word = strtok(& rcv[0]," ");
    while (word!= NULL) 
    {
        skp = BoyerMoore_skip(word, strlen(word) );

        if(skp != NULL)
        {
            i++;
            printf("this also \n");
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            continue;
        }

        printf("\n Word %s \n",word);
        bfr << word << " ";
        result_string = bfr.str();
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        j++; 
    }

    ss<<result_string;

    while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) 
    {
        writable.push_back(item);
    }

    for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator it = writable.begin(); it != writable.end(); it++)
        ++src[*it];

    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), mytransform);

    rec=dst.begin();   
    for (auto it = dst.begin(); it != dst.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->second << ":" << it->first << std::endl;


    if ((bytecount = send(*csock, (char *)ar, i *sizeof(int), 0)) == -1) 
    { // Here we cant send lenth-1. It consider exact
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }

FINISH:
    free(csock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: goto FINISH? the dreaded goto? ... are you for real?

Comment: In other words do you want only one instance of your program should be running at given time ?

Comment: You need to get a few basic concepts straight before attempting something like this. Don't use `malloc`, `free` and most of all _never_ use `goto` in C++ code. Look into Resource Allocation is Instantiation (RAII) to see how to free resources in C++ in an exception safe way.

Comment: @NIRAJRATHI: yes, I want it to run all the time in background

Comment: @SimpleFellow: what you mean? what is the problem there

Comment: @Hulk That's just C code in a .cpp file, not really C++ code. `malloc()` and `free()` are perfectly fine there. And really, using `goto` there is actually creating cleaner code than 3290358195 nested `if`s, so I wouldn't criticize it so much.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Ok, it may be necessary if you're stuck with C, but the OP is not - he seems to have a C++ compiler available, using C++ libraries. He is pulling rather huge namespaces into global scope with `using`, and the question does sound like a beginner trying to learn how to program properly. I don't feel that mixing two languages in one source file without any obvious need to do so is a good way to start, and I just wanted to point out that this is not the C++ way to write something like this.

Comment: @Hulk: I will improve it. Actually I was working with c only. But making transition to cpp. I agree with your point.

Comment: Anyways I appriciate if you can give answer or hint to my original question!

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure I understand what you want to achieve. Do you want this program as a daemon every time the system starts? It is fairly OS specific how to achieve that.

Comment: I want to keep it on server. It will keep listeing from user request and reply back! on localhost it work when I run ./deamon manually! but now want to achive how on server

Comment: All of those malloc(sizeof(int)) calls are unnecessary and harmful.  Replace them with simple stack allocation (e.g. int i; ) instead and your program will be more efficient and won't suffer from potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>


pid_t pid=fork();
if(pid<0)
exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //see no goto
else if(pid>0){
  //this is parent process, exit now
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // again no goto
 }
  else{
   //this is child or daemon
    unmask();
     pid_t childid = setsid();
     while(true){
        myTask();    //Run the Process
    sleep(60);    
   }
  }
```

Ok I studied your program and made changes. This is how your code in main should look like.

```
  using namespace std;
  using namespace boost;

  #define CHECK_THROW(condtion, code) if(condition) throw code

  void *SocketHandler(void *);
  int OpenSockets();

  int main(int argv, char **argc)
  {
    try{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        CHECK_THROW(pid<0, -5);
        if(pid==0)
        {
            //this is child or daemon
                    mode_t oldMask, newMask; 
            oldMask=unmask(newMask);
            pid_t childid = setsid();
            int hsock = OpenSocket();
            CHECK_THROW(listen(hsock, 10) == -1, -4);
            addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

            while (true) 
            {
                printf("waiting for a connectionn\n");
                csock = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
                *csock = accept(hsock, (sockaddr *) & sadr, &addr_size);
                CHECK_THROW(*csock!=-1, -7);
                printf("---------------------nReceived connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
                pthread_t thread_id = pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &SocketHandler, (void *) csock);
                pthread_detach(thread_id);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(int ierror)
    {
        switch(ierror)
        {
            case -4: fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %dn", errno); break;
            case -7: fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %dn", errno); break;
        }
      }
  }


  int OpenSockets()
  { 
     // Create your socket and return the socket handle from this function 
  }

  void *SocketHandler(void *lp){    /*blah blah */  }
```

Comment: `sleep(1)` will listen every second?

Comment: in my code also can I do `exit(EXIT_FAILURE); ` instread of `goto FINISH;`

Comment: yes u must use exit(blah blah) to exit and sleep(1) will put your process to sleep and have sweet dreams! perhaps it can still listen to in dreams and even wakeup if the sound is loud

Comment: @SimpleFellow: Can i take `hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` I could not what to keep in `openSocket()`

Comment: I dont quite understand you. OpenSocket() is a custom function and the idea is to place socket(), setsoctopt() calls inside at one location

Comment: @SimpleFellow: I could not get it, I read documentation. Do you mean to insert `int on=1;
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAYACK, &on, sizeof(on));` something like this?

Comment: @SimpleFellow: is it `unmask()` or `umask()`? and also should be declared as `mode_t umask(mode_t cmask);` if I am not wrong!